# Ruby on Rails: Create record from link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

how can I issue a create command from a link? I have an if/else statement that displays edit or create, but I haven't found the right way to create the record.

I had this, but then I have to refresh the page to get it to function, which I can't have:

```
  <% if FollowUp3Week.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first != nil %>
    <%= link_to "edit", follow_up3_week_path([FollowUp3Week.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first]) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= FollowUp3Week.create(subject_id: sub.subject_id) %>
  <% end %>
```

And I'm trying this, but no luck so far (where subjects_path is a link to the current page):

```
  <% if Baseline.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first != nil %> 
    <%= link_to "edit", baseline_path([Baseline.where(subject_id: sub.subject_id).first]) %>              
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "create", subjects_path(Baseline.create(subject_id: sub.subject_id)) %> 
  <% end %>
```

Any tips, or references I should read through, would be greatly appreciated.

I really just want the link 'create' to generate the working 'edit' link.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you give some context, like on what page this is rendered, what controller and action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only be able to create a record when you call a controller, so what you want to do in your case is make the link_to just render the url to the controller that have the create action, once the user clicks the link that will trigger a request to your controller which will run the create record.

Comment: How would that look? I'm playing with Baseline.create(subject_id: sub.subject_id) as the parameter for link_to. So if I need to render the url for the Baseline controller, where do I call that create method?

Comment: It will look something like this:
link_to "Create", :controller => "[your controller]", :action =>    "create"

And then from your controller in the create action you call Baseline.create(subject_id: sub.subject_id)